# Tikz: picture which shoud be at current page.north west is not at the right location

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a picture just at the upper left corner of a page with Tikz. But the picture I draw with the following code fails to be at the right position as shown in the attached figure. Why, and how to deal with it?

**CODE**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path [inner sep=0,,outer sep=0pt,line width=1mm,opacity=.25,draw=red,fill=blue,scale=2]
(current page.north west) (0,0)--(2,0)--(2,-2)--(0,-2)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

% Contrast with current page.south west
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] at (current page.south west)
[text width=7cm,fill=red!20,rounded corners,above right]
{
This is an absolutely positioned text in the
lower left corner. No shipout-hackery is used.
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `[shift=(current page.north west)]`. Otherwise you are just moving to the corner point and immediately move back to `(0,0)`, as it is the next `moveto` command.

Comment: Would you give more info about `moveto`? And why does `\node` in my second part of the code not need `shift`?

Comment: With [overlay] the origin is placed at the current location (baseline) in the text area.  Think of the tikzpicture as \hbox{}:, invisible but there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer why, but my guess would be that `tikz` defaults the bounding box of any image to the text area.

As mentioned in the comments `(current page.north west)` is a coordinate similar to how `(0,0)` is a coordinate. Your draw command uses absolute positioning and there is no line drawn starting at `(current page.north west)`. This is different from your `node` which is positioned using the `at` notation.

So you can basically use the coordinate and then relative positioning of your coordinates using the `++` notation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \path [inner sep=0,,outer sep=0pt,line width=1mm,opacity=.25,draw=red,fill=blue,scale=2]
        (current page.north west) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(0,-2) -- ++(-2,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```